# Is there any better way to create, and edit classes? Class type 'Role'

Tags: python

I recently started to learn classes, and here I'm trying to make a class which would perform the Role, let's say we're creating a server, and there's also the users, which do have the permission to do something. And with making the roles, I do get an error of wrong syntax, that my first problem, but I may ask, is the class made well? Could I use them in the future? The default Role, for new account is Member.!

```
class Role:
    # ROles Member, Moderator, Admin
    def __init__(self):
        self._Role = 'Member'

    def get_role(self):
        return self._Role

    def set_role(self):
        self._Role = input("~ Please set a role!")
        if self._Role = 'Member':
            self._Role = 'Member'
        elif self._Role = 'Moderator':
            self._Role = 'Moderator'
        elif self._Role = 'Admin':
            self._Role = 'Admin'
```

Comment: The syntax error is because `=` is for assignment. `==` is for checking for equality. `if self._Role = 'Member':` etc. is not valid.

Comment: What's the point of this class? It doesn't do anything. How is this better than using a regular string?

Comment: My point is to get,set the class so I could use it in future.

Comment: ```@property``` is what you are looking for